# How to access specific items in array? [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting specific items in this array.

```
[
   {
      "averages":[
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"ABC",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"ESD",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         },
      ]
   },
   {
      "averages":[
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"CCC",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"ESD",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"XXX",
         },
      ]
   },
   {
      "averages":[
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TIPO":"XXX",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"LLL",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"NU",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"XXX",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

I'm trying to separate status from type AAA

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I get the array like this:

```
    var quality = solicitacoes[0].produtor.dados[0].apiLaticinio[0].qualidade[0]
    var qualityjson = JSON.parse(quality)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(qualityjson));
```

I tried to use this material, but without success: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

What nodejs resource can I access the items in the way I mentioned?

Thanks if anyone can help me!

UPDATE:

I used this method to try to solve my problem.

```
function getStatus(arr) {
  let results = [];
  arr.forEach(avg => {
    avg.averages.forEach(element => {
      if (element["TYPE"] === 'AAA') {
        results.push(element["STATUS"])
      }
    })
  })
  return results;
}

const results = getStatus(quality)
```

But I'm getting the following result:

> TypeError: arr.forEach is not a function

Comment: Replace "items" with "quality". But I have: TypeError: array.map is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the status from the given array you can just use `Array.map()` inside `Array.map()` like below:

```
const getItems = (array = items) => {
  return array.map((arItem, _) => {
    return arItem.averages.map((nestItem, _) => {
      return nestItem.STATUS
    })
  })
}

console.log([].concat(...getItems()))

//Output:
//[
//  '0', '0', '1', '1',
//  '0', '0', '1', '1',
//  '1', '1', '1', '1',
//  '0', '1'
//]
```

However if you are trying to get the items with `TYPE='AAA'`, then you can use the following code:

```
const getTypeAAAItems = (array = items) => {
  return array.map((arItem, _) => {
    return arItem.averages.filter((nestItem) => {
      return nestItem.TYPE === 'AAA'
    })
  })
}

//Output:
//[
//  { STATUS: '0', TYPE: 'AAA' },
//  { STATUS: '1', TYPE: 'AAA' },
//  { STATUS: '0', TYPE: 'AAA' },
//  { STATUS: '1', TYPE: 'AAA' },
//  { STATUS: '1', TYPE: 'AAA' }
//]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're saying that you want to turn an array of objects with a `STATUS` field into an array of numbers. Let's say you have a single item from your above array:

```json
   {
      "averages":[
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"0",
            "TYPE":"ABC",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"ESD",
         },
         {
            "STATUS":"1",
            "TYPE":"AAA",
         },
      ]
   },
```

Assuming the above is parsed and stored as `item`:

```js
const statuses = item.averages.map(i => i.STATUS);
```

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will let you manipulate each element of an array in the same way and return the new array (which will have the same number of elements as the old one).

In this case, we take an object with a `STATUS` and `TYPE` field, and instead return only the value of the `STATUS` field. So we end up with an array of numbers; `[0, 0, 1, 1]`.

Comment: I did a test using const status = item.averages.map(i => i.STATUS);
 and got "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: It's saying that `averages` is undefined, so it looks like you haven't done the first step I mentioned, which is grabbing a single object from your array which has an array called `averages` on it.